# Change Add To Cart Button text for six different categories on all parts of the website (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

What would the php code be to change the add to cart text to something unique for each product category, on both the product archives and single product pages using one code snippet if possible? I have six product categories. I am using WooCommerce.

Basically, I have 6 categories, I'd like 5 of them to say "Order" and then 1 of them to say "Book Now"

The 6 categories are:

1. Cakes
2. Cupcakes
3. Halloween
4. Sweet Treats
5. Petal and Post
6. Baking Class

i.e. all of the categories except for "Baking Class" will say Order, while "Baking Class" will say "Book Now".

I'd like to apply to the buttons all over the website, no matter where they are displayed.

I am using Elementor to create custom Product Archives.

Update 25th October, 2022:

I have tried using the code from mujuonly's answer below. It works except for on the product archive for the Baking Classes category; which I designed using Elementor Pro: https://bunsbakery.co.za/product-category/baking-classes/

Here is the code I used:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);

function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text($text, $product) {

    if( has_term( array( 'Cakes', 'Cupcakes', 'Halloween', 'Sweet Treats', 'Petal and Post' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $text = __('Order', 'woocommerce');
    }
    if( has_term( array( 'baking-classes' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $text = __('Book Now', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);
    
    function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text($text, $product) {
    
        if( has_term( array( 'Cakes', 'Cupcakes', 'Halloween', 'Sweet Treats', 'Petal and Post' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
            $text = __('Order', 'woocommerce');
        }
        if( has_term( array( 'Baking Class' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
            $text = __('Book Now', 'woocommerce');
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

Tested OK in Single product page and Shop page.

Comment: I have added your code using Code Snippets and it is not showing "Book Now" on the "Baking Class" category: https://bunsbakery.co.za/product-category/baking-classes/

note: I have changed the category from "Baking Class" to "Baking Classes"

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but this might be doable like this:

```
// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    global $product;
    if( has_term( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks' ), 'product_cat', $product ) 
    {
        // do something if product is either in category "sneakers" or "backpacks"
        return __( 'Buy Sneakers or backback now', 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
    }
       
}
```

If you want to change it on the single product pages, you should use the filter `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` instead.
Or both if you want it on both.

Toy around with it, and see if you can get i to work.

UPDATE

So this could be your finalfunction, based on your criteria and mujuonlys answer.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);

function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text($text, $product) {

    $text = __('Order', 'woocommerce');

    if( has_term( array( 'Baking Class' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $text = __('Book Now', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: I am not clear on how to use both filters at the same time. Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Kindly see my edited question above for more details

Comment: Mujuonly gave you the complete answer for archives.

Comment: I have added @Mujuonly's code using Code Snippets and it is not showing "Book Now" on the "Baking Class" category: https://bunsbakery.co.za/product-category/baking-classes/

note: I have changed the category from "Baking Class" to "Baking Classes"

Comment: try writing `baking-classes` instead of `Baking Classes`

Comment: I have tried. I will edit my question above to include the exact code. It only works on the single product page but not the product archive. 

I created the product archive using elementor pro's theme builder. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Looks like you are using "Woocommerce Custom Product Addons" - there should be a setting in there. and there are guidelines to use custom meta in your fields. : https://acowebs.com/guideline/plugin-docs-faqs/wcpa/wcpa-custom-fields/

Comment: Yes I am, unfortunately the plug-in doesn’t have options for button text afaik. I will double check now. I would like to achieve the result using code instead of additional plugins.